# Magento Admin Form Data blank when got Session Error message

Tags: magento-1.9, adminform, form-validation, post-data, redirection

I am checking a field for unique data, I put this code:

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {
 if($data['cs']['company_name']){
                $checkCollection = Mage::getModel('test/test')->getCollection();
                $checkCollection->addFieldToFilter('company_name',$data['cs']['company_name']);
                    if(count($checkCollection)){

                        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(true);
                          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
                          Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('csmarketplace')->__('Company name should be unique.'));
                       /* echo "<pre>"; print_r($data);
                          $test = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->getFormData($data);
                          echo "<pre>"; print_r($test);
                        exit;*/

                        $this->_redirect('*/*/new');
                        return;
                    }
                }
}
```

It is working fine but the form is blank after redirection and Session error.

Can I do this via ajax, this module is admin side module.

Comment: I see you use `setFormData()`, but when rendering the form do you call `getFormData`  to get the values?

Comment: @Marius, this is my Model file, I put my code in _beforeSave(), I want that If the session error the from should retain values and at the same time the session will display the error message. This is my Ced Marketplace extension's module.

Comment: you should never involve models and the request. your code that gets data from post should go in the controller, in the `saveAction`. and the actual validation should go in the model. the validation method should throw an exception and the same controller action should catch that exception and set data and message to the session. your form should check the session for any values and display them if there are.